# Can not enable "Google Cloud Messaging for Android" at Google Cloud Console

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am following the instruction from [GCM get started](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html) and I already created a API project, however when I went to enable the Google Cloud Messaging for Android, I would get the popup like this:
[image: enable GCM], however after I checked the checkbox and click accept, the popup is keeping coming back and it seems that I could not enable the GCM here.

I tried on both Chrome and IE, neither is working. So I am not sure what I am missing here (need to configure something else?) or it is just a web site bug which I am running to. Not sure if anyone else was facing the same issue before or not.

Comment: by the way, if you guys know a better forum for this, please let me know, somehow I didn't find it. plus I like SO :-)

Comment: I cant reproduce it, so try removing it and do it over!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to confirm I am having the exact same issue currently.  I also tried some of the other APIs that require acceptance of terms and all behave the same, recurring confirmation popups.

Edit:
Okay, found the solution.  This problem seems to relate to the "new" console.  At the bottom right of the console window there is a link that says "return to original console".  Enabling the API from the original console works.